# How can I prevent react component from re-rendering by apollo usequery?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I have a react component which is included in my Tabbar(Material-ui).

And this component has lots Apollo `useQuery` hooks(15 `useQuery`) to fetch some data. I tried to use `loading` parameter which are the result of each `useQuery` in order to prevent useless rendering.

```
    const { loading: loading_1, data: data_1} = useQuery<GetQuery1>(QUERY_1);
    const { loading: loading_2, data: data_2} = useQuery<GetQuery2>(QUERY_2);
    const { loading: loading_3, data: data_3} = useQuery<GetQuery3>(QUERY_3);

    // . . .

    const { loading: loading_15, data: data_15} = useQuery<GetQuery15>(QUERY_15);

    if (
        loading_1 ||
        loading_2 ||
        loading_3 ||
        // ... loading parameters
        loading_10
    ) {
        return <span>Loading...</span>;
    } 

    return (
        <>
            {loading_11 ? ("Loading ... 11") : (<MyComponent_A data={data_11} options={data_6,data_7}/> )}
            {loading_12 ? ("Loading ... 12") : (<MyComponent_B data={data_12} options={data_1,data_2,data_8}/> )}
            {loading_13 ? ("Loading ... 13") : (<MyComponent_C data={data_13} options={data_4,data_7,data_9}/> )}
            {loading_14 ? ("Loading ... 14") : (<MyComponent_D data={data_14} options={data_8,data_10}/> )}
            {loading_15 ? ("Loading ... 15") : (<MyComponent_E data={data_15} options={data_3}/> )}
        </>
    );
```

When this component first appeared, I was able to control rendering because loading parameters of `useQuery` hooks return `true`.

However, when I reopen this component(I just clicked on the other tabs and came back), this component render 15 times always(I just printed it using `console.log()` for each component). I checked the loading parameters and those never had a `true`.

So when I re-opened this component, I didn't even get a loading message and it felt like it was stopping a bit.

How can I solve this?

Comment: If the component unmounts and the mounts, loading should return true until the data is fetched from the cache, so you may be seeing a bug. As an aside, you probably don't need 15 queries. You can request multiple query fields in a single operation which will result in a single request to your server.

Comment: I suggest putting the related useQuery inside of MyComponent_A, MyComponent_B, ... and handling the loading/error states inside each individual component. You also know that if you cause an error it will only affect one component instead of the rendering of your whole app

Comment: @DanielRearden May I ask how you would request multiple query fields in a single operation?

Comment: Edit: Found out you can do Apollo Query Batching https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/performance/query-batching/

Answer (score 1):

A boolean parameter called skip and it checks whether the query should work or not, prevents unnecessary requests to the server.Like this ->

```
const { data } = useQuery(GET_FILTERED_CONTENTS, {
    variables: { page, limit },
    skip: !shouldQuery,
});
```